# insert from text file into textBox

Tags: c#

So what I would like to do is load a txt document into C# and in each line of the txt document have the part write into a different textbox from the text file.

```
NTM-120 = textBox1
NTM-130 = textBox2
NTM-140   etc....
NTM-150
NTM-160
NTM-170
```

is this possible?

something like this?????

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("yourFileName.txt"))
{
    textBox1.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    textBox2.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    textBox3.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    textBox4.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    textBox5.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    textBox6.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    textBox7.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    textBox8.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    textBox9.Text = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: Any reason you tagged this sql? I see no sql in the question... Or of course the code you've tried so far.

Comment: It depends. What kind of textbox? On a web page or on a windows forms app?

Comment: means .... textbox1.text=NTM-120 rite ?

Comment: Yes Revanayya something like that

Comment: Dear @user3324892, you should really provide some information about what you tried, where you are stuck, what do want to do with the info from the textboxes, etc.

Comment: @ user3324892..Yes it is possible..As I described in earlier post..Take text file to list and traverse it and assign to textbox

Comment: Updated my question with something im looking for.  might that work?

Comment: @user3324892, why don't you try?

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
int count=1;
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Data.txt");
int totalTxtBoxControls=20;
if(lines.Count==totalTxtBoxControls)
{
((TextBox)this.Controls.Find("TextBox" + count, true)[0]).Text = line[count-1];
count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you haven't really thought about how to do it nor tried it, but basically

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("source.txt");
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    // put you logic on which line goes to which textbox
}
```

Eh?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        int lineNumber = 0;
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
           lineNumber++;
           var readLine = sr.ReadLine();
           if (readLine != null)
           {
               TextBox textBox = GetControle(this, "textBox"+lineNumber);
                if (textBox != null)
                {
                    textBox.Text = readLine;
                }
            }
        }
     }
}

private TextBox GetControle(Control ctrlContainer, string name)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in ctrlContainer.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        {
            if (ctrl.Name == name)
            {
                return (TextBox)ctrl;
            }
        }
         if (ctrl.HasChildren)
            GetControle(ctrl, name);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It dynamically creates a textbox for every line in your text file!

```
TableLayoutPanel tlp = new TableLayoutPanel();
tlp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

int row = 0;
foreach (string s in File.ReadAllLines("file.txt"))
{
    tlp.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle());

    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.Text = s;
    tlp.Controls.Add(tb, 0, row++);
}

this.Controls.Add(tlp);
```